# How can I detect when a MapMarker is clicked/tapped?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I'm building a swiftui app and am trying to implement a searchview for locations. I'm currently displaying the search results as annotations and want the user to be able to select them by tapping on them.

Is this possible, as the Annotations aren't views, I can't use a gesture modifier to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use the system style. An [apple developer forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659748) made me aware that the image used for MapMarker is available as a system symbol/in sf symbols, so this is the implementation I came up with.

```swift
MapAnnotation(coordinate: result.coordinate) {
                    Button {
                        selectedDestination = result
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: result == selectedDestination ? "mappin.circle.fill" : "mappin.circle")
                    }
                }
```

The size of the Image still has to be adjusted and the foreground color as well, but it works in principle.